Strange repetition in loss curves (Tensorflow)
I am training on a custom dataset (of ~200,000 images) that has been constructed to sample from three different datasets at equal frequencies, the main construction steps are:
sample_dict = {"var_name": var, ...}
train = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(sample_dict(train_array)).shuffle(100)
split_train = [train.filter(lambda sample: sample['label']==label) for label in [0, 1, 2]]
train = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets(split_train, [1/3,1/3,1/3).batch(128)
train = train.prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


Training is somewhat converging but my metrics and losses have a strange repeating pattern. These are stateful metrics that I have added to the model properties so they reset every epoch. The repeating pattern doesn't align with epochs or with the filtered dataset cardinality (1,386). I'm racking my brain for things to try. Any suggestions appreciated.
I get the repeating pattern shown below for my critic and generator loss, as well as other metrics
.
Update:
I've realised my dataset is ~200,000 images and these oscillations have a period of ~200,00. I think it must be related to how I'm constructing my dataset.
